# Issue using MVC 4 in Mono Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mono

I am using Debian to host an application that is built using MVC. I am using Mariadb as backend.
The application works fine in Windows platform but when I try to run it on Linux using mono framework it generates following error.

`System.IO.FileNotFoundException`

Exception origin:`DotNetOpenAuth.core`

I am using following versions:

`MVC 4`

`Mono 3.2.3`

Is there any compatibility issue or I am missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution by myself just add reference to `log4net.dll`